# np.array not passing an array with the same first dimension = value error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

From my main df, I used groupby to slice a section and make an new df to plot the selection

```
#Number of disasters declared per year
yearly_dcount = df_time.groupby(['Start_year']).size()

#Series to pd.df
yearly_dcount=pd.DataFrame(yearly_dcount)
yearly_dcount.columns=['Number_of_Disasters']
```

However, this made the Start_year column, the index of the new df = yearly_dcount, which has made it difficult for me to plot, also as the number of disasters is an object.

So, I used np to convert the data to arrays

```
x = np.array([yearly_dcount.index])
y = np.array(yearly_dcount['Number_of_Disasters'])


plt.plot(x,y,color='#0066FF')
plt.show()
```

The x is returned as an int 64 (1,55) but the y is returned as a int 32 (55,).
And I receive the error:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1, 55) and (55,)

Any help on the easiest way to plot this data would be appreciated.

```
Start_year,Number_of_Disasters
1959,1
1964,115
1965,429
1966,120
1967,197
1968,162
1969,505
1970,221
1971,170
1972,526
1973,862
1974,618
1975,459
1976,586
1977,1160
1978,439
1979,476
1980,195
1981,60
1982,147
```

```
print(yearly_dcount.columns.dtype)
object
```

Comment: `x = np.array(yearly_dcount.index)` ? You added an extra dimension to `x`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to extract data as numpy arrays, you can plot directly using pandas:

```
df.plot.bar(x='Start_year', y='Number_of_Disasters')
```

[image: pandas barplot]

Alternatively:

```
df.plot(x='Start_year', y='Number_of_Disasters')
```

[image: pandas line plot]

Comment: normally yes, but the df I have the 'Start_year' is the Index, so it returns a key error. Which I've been trying to get around with the np.array

Comment: then use `df.reset_index().plot(…)`

Comment: I tried this as well, but then the dates are replaced with 0 - 55

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the original problematic dataframe?

Comment: ```yearly_dcount.reset_index().plot('Start_year','Number_of_Disasters')``` -- This ended up working, I must have done something wrong when I tried it before! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `y = np.array(yearly_dcount[['Number_of_Disasters']])`